# JsMockito - How do i get jsmockito to ignore argument

Tags: javascript, mocking

I would like to get jsMockito to ignore my parameter inputs into a function call.

Lets say i have the following codes :-

var mockedCommand = mock(CoreCommand);

when(mockedCommand).parseCommand(myfakeInput, myfakeInput2, myFakeInput3).thenReturn("Hello");

how do i get jsMockito to ignore myFakeInput,  myFakeInput2 and myFakeInput3 and just return "Hello"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to use JsHamcrest object matcher solve my issue.

```
    var Employee = function()
    { 
        this.getName = function(name)
        {
            return "Hello " + name;
        }

        this.updateAddress = function(emp)
        {
            return emp; 
        }
    }; 

    test( "a test", function() {

      var mockObject = mock(Employee);

      var fakeAddress = {
        address1 : "Addr1", 
        address2 : "Addr2", 
        address3 : "Addr3", 
      };


    var nonMatchingAddress = {
        address1 : "DifferentAddr1", 
        address2 : "DifferentAddr2", 
        address3 : "DifferentAddr3", 
      };        

      var realAddress = {
        address1 : "123", 
        address2 : "456", 
        address3 : "789", 
      };

      // Ok 
      //when(mockObject).updateAddress(fakeAddress).thenReturn(realAddress);
      //var argumentMatchingReturnResult = mockObject.updateAddress(fakeAddress);
      //console.log(argumentMatchingReturnResult);
      //equal(argumentMatchingReturnResult, realAddress, "passing in matching argument.");

      // Not OK - return undefined 
      //when(mockObject).updateAddress(fakeAddress).thenReturn(realAddress);
      //var argumentMatchingReturnResult = mockObject.updateAddress(nonMatchingAddress);
      //console.log(argumentMatchingReturnResult); // comes out undefined 
      //equal(argumentMatchingReturnResult, realAddress, "passing in matching argument.");

      // uses JsHamcrest.Matchers.object() here 
      // match any object here 
      // when(mockObject).updateAddress(JsHamcrest.Matchers.object()).thenReturn(realAddress);
      // var result = mockObject.updateAddress(realAddress);
      //console.log(result);

      //notEqual(result, undefined, "ensure return result is not undefined");

      // uses JsHamcrest.Matchers.typeOf() here 
       when(mockObject).updateAddress(JsHamcrest.Matchers.typeOf('object')).thenReturn(realAddress);
       var result = mockObject.updateAddress(realAddress);
       console.log(result);
       notEqual(result, undefined, "ensure return result is not undefined");

});
```